# LINQ search in list

Tags: c#, linq

I have this list

```
var allPlaces = new[]
{
    new { Name = "Red apple", OtherKnownNames = "Green" },
    new { Name = "Orange", OtherKnownNames = "" },
    new { Name = "Banana", OtherKnownNames = "the" },
}.ToList();
```

my query is "the apple"

my code does not return me first and third item, query has 2 words separated by a space, I want if any word in query starts with the Name or OtherKnownName should be returned.

```
var query = "the apple";
var queryParts = query.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var filteredList =
    allPlaces
        .Where(p =>
            p.Name
                .Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Any(pp => queryParts.Any(qp => qp.StartsWith(pp)))
            || p.OtherKnownNames
                .Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .Any(pp => queryParts.Any(qp => qp.StartsWith(pp))))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Why should it return the first item? Only the last seems to meet your criteria.

Comment: Will this code compile with `List<var>`

Comment: does not or should not ? maybe if you syntax is can compile it will be return  
> Red apple Green
> Banana the

Comment: I fixed the syntax for the OP. He/she should read [ask].

Comment: How do you feel about case?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to ignore case, and accept names that match the beginning of query words (based on your example with `StartsWith`).

Use an extension method to make splitting without empty entries nicer:

```
public static string[] SplitNoEmpty(this string s, params char[] seps) => s.Split(seps, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

You can simply split up the `query` string and search for matches:

```
var qwords = query.SplitNoEmpty(' ');

var ans = allPlaces.Where(p => qwords.Any(qw => (p.Name + " " + p.OtherKnownNames).SplitNoEmpty(' ')
                                                                                  .Any(nw => qw.StartsWith(nw, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
                                     )
                   )
                   .ToList();
```